# Save huxtable in R to file in LaTex format

Tags: r, latex, huxtable

How can I save a huxtable to a file in LaTeX (.tex) format? I did find [this code](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/reference/to_latex.html) to print LaTeX tables to the console:

```
library(huxtable)
ht <- huxtable(
        a = 1:3,
        b = letters[1:3]
      )
print_latex(ht)
```

Does the huxtable package have a native way to save the table to disk or do we need a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The huxtable package has a function to do that: `quick_latex(ht, file = "Table.tex", open = FALSE)`.

Comment: NB the difference with the other answer. `quick_latex()` prints an entire tex document. `to_latex()` or `to_latex()` just print the tex for the table itself

Answer (score 2):

There might be other ways but using `capture.output` works -

```
library(huxtable)
capture.output(print_latex(ht), file = 'output.tex')
```

Comment: Or you could just use `cat(to_latex(ht), file = 'output.tex')`.